# How to define custom projection EPSG:5714 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg

I have a series of raster files with the CRS EPSG:5714. I need to define this CRS in QGIS but I'm fairly new to this and have no idea how to define the proj4 CRS for this. I searched at spatialreference.org but the proj4 information is blank. Can anyone help me define it in QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

EPSG:5714 is a vertical coordinate system.

QGIS can only handle 2-dimensional CRS correctly, so there is no chance to get it defined as custom CRS.

Comment: That explains why I've been having so much trouble. Thanks for the answer